# Compiling and running C program via ssh from windows and mac -- windows gives seg fault

Tags: c, linux, macos, segmentation-fault

So I have a particular C program that works on my Mac when I compile and run. I also tested via ssh on my school's linux computers, and it runs fine. However, my friend, who has a PC, used PuTTY to access the linux computers, and with the exact same code, he always gets a seg fault while running the program. Why might this be?

The code is listed below. I have provided the entire code, but the issue, as we found through print statements, lies in the `int counter = 0;` line early on in the main block:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct Nodes{
    char firstName[40];
    char lastName[40];
    char townName[70];
    struct Nodes* next;
} Node;

//-- create head global variable.
Node* head;

//-- check if a char array contains a dash (to check for the 9 digit zip code)
bool containsDash(char* string){
    char *s;
    s = strchr (string, '-');
    if (s==NULL){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}

//-- insert node after ptr, with given attributes.
void insertNodeAfter(Node* ptr, char* fName, char* lName, char* tName){
    Node* newPtr = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    strcpy(newPtr->firstName, fName);
    strcpy(newPtr->lastName, lName);
    strcpy(newPtr->townName, tName);
    newPtr->next = ptr->next;
    ptr->next = newPtr;
}

//-- insert node before head.
Node* insertNodeBeforeHead(char* fName, char* lName, char* tName){
    Node* ptr = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    strcpy(ptr->firstName, fName);
    strcpy(ptr->lastName, lName);
    strcpy(ptr->townName, tName);

    ptr->next = head;
    head = ptr;
    return ptr;
}

//-- check if char array starts with start
bool startsWith(char *start, char *str){
    size_t lenstart = strlen(start);
    size_t lenstr = strlen(str);
    if (lenstart > lenstr){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return strncmp(start, str, lenstart) == 0;
    }
}

//-- check if nodes have equal attributes.
bool nodesEqual(Node* first, Node* second){
    if (strcmp(first->firstName, second->firstName) == 0 && strcmp(first->lastName, second->lastName) == 0 && strcmp(first->townName, second->townName) == 0){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

//-- delete ptr node
void deleteNode(Node* ptr){
    if (nodesEqual(ptr, head)){
        head = ptr->next;
        free(ptr);
    }
    else{
        Node* temp = head;
        while(1){
            if (nodesEqual(temp->next, ptr)){
                temp->next = temp->next->next;
                free(ptr);
                break;
            }   
            else{
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }
    }
}

//-- delete node with the given first and last name
void deleteNodeByInfo(char* fName, char* lName){
    if (head == NULL){
        return;
    }
    Node* temp = head;
    while(1){
        if (strcmp(temp->firstName, fName) == 0 && strcmp(temp->lastName, lName) == 0){
            deleteNode(temp);
            break;
        }
        if (temp->next != NULL){
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
}

//-- take the current attributes and make a node in the correct spot
void insertNodeInCorrectSpot(char* fName, char* lName, char* tName){
    //-- take 2 pointers separated by one link, look for a spot to insert node between these pointers
    Node* pointer = head;
    Node* pointer2 = head;
    if (pointer->next != NULL){
        pointer2 = pointer2->next;
    }
    else{
        pointer2 = pointer2->next;
    }
    if (strcmp(tName, pointer->townName) < 0){
        Node* newHead = insertNodeBeforeHead(fName, lName, tName);
        head = newHead;
    }
    else{
        while(strcmp(tName, pointer2->townName) > 0){
            if (pointer2->next != NULL){
                pointer = pointer->next;
                pointer2 = pointer2->next;
            }
            else{
                pointer = pointer2;
                break;
            }
        }
        insertNodeAfter(pointer, fName, lName, tName);
    }
}

//-- remove spaces at the end of a string
void removeSpacesAtEnd(char* input){
    int end = strlen(input) - 1;
    if (isspace(input[end])){
        input[end] = '\0';
    }
    if (isspace(input[--end])){
        removeSpacesAtEnd(input);
    }
}

//-- print the attributes of a given node
void printNode(Node* pointer){
    printf("%s", pointer->firstName);
    // printf("%s", " ");
    printf("%s", pointer->lastName);
    // printf("%s", " ");
    printf("%s\n", pointer->townName);
}

// -d is option for debug.

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int counter = 0; //-- keep counter to keep track of cycle
    char *tempChar, *tempFName, *tempLName, *tempTName;

    //-- create buffers to store first name, last name, town name
    tempChar = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    tempFName = (char*)malloc(40*sizeof(char));
    tempLName = (char*)malloc(40*sizeof(char));
    tempTName = (char*)malloc(70*sizeof(char));
    while(counter < 600){
        fgets(tempChar, 100, stdin);
        //-- remove newline delimiter
        char *pos;
        if ((pos=strchr(tempChar, '\n')) != NULL)
            *pos = '\0';
        //-- The text will always go in a cycle of 6. Use modular division to figure out what is in the line being read.
        if (counter % 6 == 0){
            strncpy(tempFName, tempChar, strlen(tempChar));
            removeSpacesAtEnd(tempFName);
            strcat(tempFName, " ");
        }
        else if (counter % 6 == 1){
            strncpy(tempLName, tempChar, strlen(tempChar));
            removeSpacesAtEnd(tempLName);
            if (counter == 1){
                size_t len = strlen(tempChar);
                tempLName[len] = '\0';
            }
            strcat(tempLName, " ");
        }
        else if (counter % 6 == 3){
            if (containsDash(tempChar)){
                strncpy(tempTName, tempChar, strlen(tempChar)-15);
            }
            else{
                strncpy(tempTName, tempChar, strlen(tempChar)-9);
            }
            removeSpacesAtEnd(tempTName);
            strcat(tempTName, " ");
        }
        else if (counter % 6 == 4){
            if (counter == 4){
                head = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
                strcpy(head->firstName, tempFName);
                strcpy(head->lastName, tempLName);
                strcpy(head->townName, tempTName);
            }
            else{
                insertNodeInCorrectSpot(tempFName, tempLName, tempTName);
            }
            memset(tempFName, 0, strlen(tempFName));
            memset(tempLName, 0, strlen(tempLName));
            memset(tempTName, 0, strlen(tempTName));
        }
        memset(tempChar, 0, strlen(tempChar));
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: The description could be better. What are you transferring (and how) to the remote linux machine -- the source or a binary? If source: what does compiling it with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` output? If binary: how did you cross-compile? In general: Did you try to debug with e.g. `gdb`?

Comment: Did you debug it ? Try and show the results.   And don't **cast result of malloc**  and you never `free` any allocated memory . This can cause memory leak .

Comment: Run it in a debugger.

Comment: I compile using g++. I am not quite sure how to use gdb also. And ameyCU, if I don't cast result of malloc, what should I do exactly? (I am just copying example code from class).

Comment: @user3642365  `char *` cast  is not needed .  And for using `gdb` refer this link -http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/debug-c-program-using-gdb/ .  This is `c` not `c++` , use `gcc` .

Comment: @user3642365 it's C-code, so you should compile with `gcc`, NOT with `g++`. In C, `void *` is implicitly convertible for a reason (in C++, it's not). Also, please update your question with respect to my earlier comment, it's really necessary to know whether you are both compiling on that remote linux host or just trying the same binary there.

Comment: This code contains 8 errors when compiling with Xcode 7.1 as `.c`.  For example `bool` is a C++ type.

Comment: @trojanfoe, not it's not ... it's just `#include <stdbool.h>` missing for c. The code is clearly c, so the correct way is to fix the c errors.

Comment: Indeed; after including `<stdbool.h>` it compiles perfectly.  What input does this program require?

Comment: The problem is mainly that it compiles and runs perfectly on my Mac, and the linux machine through ssh. My friend has the same code, accesses linux machine using PuTTY, compiles fine but running gives a seg fault.

Comment: The line that gives the error is int counter  = 0;

Comment: @user3642365 is he transferring his own version of the source file through `scp` or just using yours? The line you reference is definitely NOT the source of the error, try to compile with `gcc -g3 -O0` and run it in `gdb` to get some insight...

Comment: @ameyCU said I am not freeing any allocated memory leak anywhere. What variables do I have to free?

Comment: @user3642365  You need to free those pointers to which use `malloc` to allocate.

Comment: *If* the OP uses a C++ compiler, the code is treated as C++. Telling the OP to use a C compiler as it were C code does not refer to the question (dispite the fact the question is tagged wrongly) @FelixPalmen

Comment: @alk, no it doesn't, it's just a hint how to do better and that's what comments are for.

Comment: Why do you tag the question C if using a C++ compiler?

Comment: "*that's what comments are for*" fair enough ... @FelixPalmen

Comment: @alk thanks. Indeed, you can *either* question the tag *or* the compiler used ;) As the whole code looks a lot more like [tag:c] than like [tag:c++], I opted for the second....

Comment: Please provide the **entire** test case, that is, the code, the compiler, the compiler options, and the input on which the code fails.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this is the same problem your friend ran into. But after adding an inclusion of stdbool.h, I was able to get a segmentation fault on my mac by running it like this:

```
$ ./testit < /etc/group
```

It's faulting here:

```
//-- remove spaces at the end of a string
void removeSpacesAtEnd(char* input){
    int end = strlen(input) - 1;
    if (isspace(input[end])){
        input[end] = '\0';
    }
    if (isspace(input[--end])){
        removeSpacesAtEnd(input);
    }
}
```

It's faulting on the input:

> "# Note that this file is consulted directly only when the system i"

This line contains a space in the second-to-last position, but not the last position. This causes the `removeSpacesAtEnd()` function to recurse infinitely until it fills up the call stack.

The simplest fix would be to move the second "if" block inside the first, so that it only executes when the last character of the input was a space:

```
//-- remove spaces at the end of a string
void removeSpacesAtEnd(char* input){
    int end = strlen(input) - 1;
    if (isspace(input[end])){
        input[end] = '\0';
        if (isspace(input[--end])){
            removeSpacesAtEnd(input);
        }
    }
}
```

After fixing that, the program now crashes for me here:

```
    else if (counter % 6 == 3){
        if (containsDash(tempChar)){
            strncpy(tempTName, tempChar, strlen(tempChar)-15);
        }
        else{
            strncpy(tempTName, tempChar, strlen(tempChar)-9); <-- Here
        }
```

So, this program may have other problems.

You should learn how to use a debugger. It's really not hard and it will save you a lot of frustrating time. Here's how I used `lldb`, the OSX debugger, to figure out the second crash:

Compile the program with debugging symbols (-g):

```
$ gcc -g -o testit testit.c
$
```

Invoke the debugger on the "testit" program. On linux you'd use gdb instead of lldb, but the commands that I'm going to use here will be the same.

```
$ lldb testit
(lldb) target create "testit"
Current executable set to 'testit' (x86_64).
(lldb)
```

Run "testit < /etc/group":

```
(lldb) run < /etc/group
Process 40951 launched: '/Users/kherron/x/testit' (x86_64)
Process 40951 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0xc882f9, 0x00007fff8bde3c69 libsystem_platform.dylib`_platform_bzero$VARIANT$Unknown + 41, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x100200000)
    frame #0: 0x00007fff8bde3c69 libsystem_platform.dylib`_platform_bzero$VARIANT$Unknown + 41
libsystem_platform.dylib`_platform_bzero$VARIANT$Unknown:
->  0x7fff8bde3c69 <+41>: rep    
    0x7fff8bde3c6a <+42>: stosb  %al, %es:(%rdi)
    0x7fff8bde3c6b <+43>: movq   %rdx, %rax
    0x7fff8bde3c6e <+46>: popq   %rbp
(lldb)
```

Yeah, that's all gobbledygook to me too. Don't worry about it. Let's look at the stack of function calls that got it here. "bt" is "backtrace", which prints the call stack.

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0xc882f9, 0x00007fff8bde3c69 libsystem_platform.dylib`_platform_bzero$VARIANT$Unknown + 41, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x100200000)
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff8bde3c69 libsystem_platform.dylib`_platform_bzero$VARIANT$Unknown + 41
    frame #1: 0x00007fff8e90e40d libsystem_c.dylib`stpncpy + 70
    frame #2: 0x00007fff8e980f12 libsystem_c.dylib`__strncpy_chk + 38
    frame #3: 0x0000000100001c20 testit`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff5fbffb70) + 752 at testit.c:201
    frame #4: 0x00007fff8b56c5c9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
(lldb)
```

Frame 3 looks like a line in your program. Let's look at it.

```
(lldb) up 3
frame #3: 0x0000000100001c20 testit`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff5fbffb70) + 752 at testit.c:201
   198                  strncpy(tempTName, tempChar, strlen(tempChar)-15);
   199              }
   200              else{
-> 201                  strncpy(tempTName, tempChar, strlen(tempChar)-9);
   202              }
   203              removeSpacesAtEnd(tempTName);
   204              strcat(tempTName, " ");
```

Okay, print the value of tempChar at the time.

```
(lldb) p tempChar
(char *) $0 = 0x0000000100104b80 "##"
```

To make the point clear, print out the value of the expression "strlen(tempChar)-9":

```
(lldb) p strlen(tempChar) - 9
error: 'strlen' has unknown return type; cast the call to its declared return type
error: 1 errors parsing expression
(lldb) p (int)(strlen(tempChar)) - 9
(int) $1 = -7
```

So, it's passing a negative length to strlen().